# add content to the end of a .js file via ssh command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how to add content/code to the end of a .js file that already has code in it using ssh command.

ie....

```
touch ./ap/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
Maintain current code
echo "add custom end code only"> ./ap/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
```

Comment: You want `>>` to append rather than overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh`command is used to connect to another server.

What you can do append text to the end of a file is to `echo "something" >> /your/file`.

So based on your code:

```
touch ./ap/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
Maintain current code
echo "add custom end code only" >> ./ap/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
                                ^
                                |_ changed this
```

By the way, the `touch` part is unnecessary. When echoing inside the file, the date of the file will be updated. And if file does not exist, it will be automatically created with `echo`.

Comment: Can someone please mark my question up.  Someone marked it down and I don't know why.